# How can i combine multiple XAML files using C# in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, xaml

I'm trying to combine multiple XAML files to make a big XAML file with different elements, how can I make that happen if I have like 10 XAML single files?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean like a [MergedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: please clarify your question ... Is it data you're reading? otherwise, like @clcto said, are you looking at merging dictionaries? are you looking to have a program that copies several xmls into one?

Comment: Does the order matter or you want the *elements* to be combined?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You can then use the [ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#merged_resource_dictionaries) tag.

```
   <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="#d0157820" x:Key="muddyBrush"/>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="firstXamlFile.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="secondXamlFile.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="anotherXamlFile.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge multiple XAML file using merge distionary in App.XAML file. this will apply on all controls of the application.

like..

```
<Application.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="your1stXamlFile.xaml" />
     <ResourceDictionary Source="Youe2ndXAMLFile.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use UserControls? E.g. you have several user controls that are just used and displayed in the main window.

Comment: I would suggest you to adding some link to documentation on user controls in WPF, so OP can do some reading